# Unable to Display images in Cordova App Windows

Tags: cordova, windows, ionic-framework

My application works like a charm on Android.
I have used following concept to display images in Android App.

```
<img class="myClass"/>

.myClass{
    content:url('test.png');
}
```

Its working fine on Android.
But Same App on windows doesn't show anything.
Background images are displaying correctly but other images are not displayed on windows app.

Can Anybody Help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they added that in IE 11. I do it like this:

```
.myClass{
    background: url('test.png') no-repeat;
    width: 33px;    /* Your image's width */
    height: 33px;   /* Your image's height */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: According to w3schools and css tricks, it should be supported in ie8+ See: https://css-tricks.com/css-content/